# Sql Grouping by on a range of year

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is my table Orders

[image]

If I want to have the count of orders in each exact year, I simply can write this query

```
Select COUNT(*) CountOfOrders, Year(OrderDate) Year  
From Orders 
Group by YEAR(OrderDate)
```

so having this resultset

[image]

But what should Id do if I need to have this result set?

```
CoundOfOrder       FromYear_toYear
     5            2005-2010
     4            2010-2015
```

Comment: How do you do the cutoff between periods? Shouldn't `2010-2015`have either 5 or 6 (depending if you count 2010 in both periods on not)?

Comment: Based on your example data and results it is impossible to determine which range 2010 is counted in.

Comment: @jpw: It could be optional. by 2, 3 or 5 years. It depends on data. As you see above there is no order on 2011.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this query. This will help you in the simplest way.

```
SELECT  COUNT(*),(CONVERT(VARCHAR,MIN(year(orderdate)))+'-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,MAX(year(orderdate)))) AS yearRange
FROM orders
GROUP BY FLOOR(Year(OrderDate) /5)
```

You Can refer the link [SQL_Fiddle_Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e5c05/39) that uses your example to form this query.

Answer (score 4):

```
Select COUNT(*) CountOfOrders, 
CASE WHEN Year(OrderDate) BETWEEN 2005 AND 2009 THEN '2005-2009'
     WHEN Year(OrderDate) BETWEEN 2010 AND 2015 THEN '2010-2015'
END AS Year  
From Orders 
Group by 
CASE WHEN Year(OrderDate) BETWEEN 2005 AND 2009 THEN '2005-2009'
     WHEN Year(OrderDate) BETWEEN 2010 AND 2015 THEN '2010-2015'
END
```

Note that I adjusted your date ranges, or you wouldn't get meaningful data, counting some things in 2 categories.

Comment: tombom; So, what if we would have tons of data. Is there any dynamic approach instead of hard coding? Another point is maybe user want to specify the range. sometimes 5 or 2 or anything.

Comment: You'd have to write a procedure in which you'd create the statement first with dynamic sql. But since passing multiple date ranges to a procedure could be difficult, I wouldn't do it on database layer.